# Visual Studio 2017 cannot not find project items in referenced projects

Tags: resharper, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I have got very weird Visual Studio 2017 Professional behaviour.

I have a solution which has seven .Net Core libraries and a Asp.Net Core project.

As expected, some libraries are referencing others and so on.

However, when I add a new class/interface in a project and try to reference project items from other projects, it just does not find it and I get compile-time error (CS0246). I tried to use SmartTag bubble as well as adding the namespace manually, but I still get same behaviour.

**The scenario is, just for argument sake,**

Project A is a .Net Core Class Library
Project A has a public class Foo,

Project B is a .Net Core Class Library,
Project A is referenced to Project B
Project B has a class Person,

```
using ProjectA;
public Foo Foo {get;set;} // throws error.
```

Even sometimes, when I type the namespace via using statement, although the project is referenced, it does not coming up in the intellisense.

The things I have done so far is;

I had resharper installed, but completely removed it now.

I repaired Visual Studio 2017.

I tried to restore via dotnet cli too.

Sometimes restarting VS solves the issue until I create another class or interface.

Any ideas why this is happening

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like "Enable Lightweight Solution Load" option caused this. I disabled lightweight solution load feature, things got back to normal. I hope it will help others in case you come across with this issue.